# Equal value in date did not showing

Tags: php, mysqli

i have this code but when i run it the equal value is did not show up only the greater than value was shown. example in my time i have 09-26-2015 in my database is also 09-26-2015 but how come it did not show up ?

```
$new_time = date("m-d-Y H:i:s", strtotime('-9 hours'));

$kuwery=mysqli_query($link,"select * from caritas_request_service 
where hospital= '".$hsptal."' and status='".$status."' and  doctor='".$name."'
     and date >= '".$new_time."'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use this data format in mysql. It is using `Y-m-d H:i:s`, and on the purpose. One can easily compare dates in this format, while trying to compare your format one will end up in a total mess.

Just change date field format to `datetime`, fix already existing data, and make your code

```
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-9 hours'));
```

You have to understand that you don't have to store your data in the same format it gonna be used. Data have to be stored in the proper format. And then reformatted, if needed, at show time